# How do I get an input to equal a certain amount of characters?

Tags: python, validation, string-length

Our teacher has told us to make a program that validates a postcode as a Northern Ireland postcode. That means it must have the letters "BT" in it and must equal 8 characters. In the code below I managed to get the letters part working. However, he did not go into detail on how to make the input equal 8 characters. He mentioned using .length() and validation(try and except), but I'm unsure how to use .length() to get 8 characters. Here's my code:

```
postcode = input("Please enter an Northern Ireland postcode:")
BT = "BT"
while BT not in postcode:
    postcode = input("That isn't a Northern Ireland postcode. Try again:")
print("This is a Northern Ireland postcode")
```

Comment: `if len(postcode) != 8`?

Comment: Tried that and it worked, thanks.

Comment: [Ask User for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of characters in a String, you can use `len(postcode)`.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation regarding `len()`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len